# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'device_type' in torch.cuda.autocast

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network

```
with autocast(device_type='cuda', dtype=torch.float16):
    a=0.00000000000000001
    print(a)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'device_type'
```

I got this error in another tool I was using so I wanted to reproduce it and I run the above dummy code and I got it again. Anyone knows if it's a pytorch, cudatoolkit problem or something else?
These are the relative packages I have in my anaconda environment:

pytorch                   1.9.0           py3.8_cuda11.1_cudnn8.0.5_0    pytorch
python                    3.8.15               h7a1cb2a_2
cudatoolkit               11.1.74              h6bb024c_0    nvidia

And this is the error I initially came across in the training loop of a classification model I was using.

```
with autocast(dtype=self.precision):
TypeError: __init()__ got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'
```

Comment: It looks like the autocast class doesn’t accept device_type as argument. Is that class from PyTorch? If so, have you checked the docs of the class?

Answer (score 1):

If you're intending to use autocast module from pytorch, use it as following-

```
torch.autocast(device_type='cuda', dtype=torch.float16)
```